# c++ - What is the difference between using and not using const in Copy Constructor?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants, copy-constructor

This code have error.

```
[Error] no matching function for call to Complex::Complex(Complex)
```

But when this code write that `Complex(const Complex & newComplex)`,

just use const, this code works fine.

why?? I don't know why. Please tell me the answer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex {
    double re, im;
public:
    Complex(double _re = 0, double _im = 0): re(_re), im(_im) {}
    Complex(Complex & newComplex) {
        re = newComplex.re;
        im = newComplex.im;
    }
     ~Complex() {}
    Complex operator + (Complex & inputComplex) {
        Complex tempComplex;
        tempComplex.re = re + inputComplex.re;
        tempComplex.im = im + inputComplex.im;
    return tempComplex;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Complex c1(1, 0), c2(2, 1);
    Complex c3(c1 + c2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Const references behave differently than normal references, when they are passed an `rvalue` (basically a temporary object).

When you bind a `const` reference to a temporary object, it extends the lifetime of the temporary and brings it to the scope of the reference. Non-const references cannot do this, so your constructor will not accept `c1 + c2` (whose return type is a temporary object) as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter of type `T &` is an lvalue reference. An lvalue reference has to reference an lvalue (and a temporary object isn't an lvalue).

A temporary object (such as you get from `c1+c2`) isn't an lvalue, so a reference to (non-const) T can't bind to it.

Although it's still a reference to an lvalue, a reference to const T (i.e., a `T const &` or `const T &`) is allowed to bind to a temporary object.

For some circumstances (but probably not this case) you might want to consider using move constructor that uses an rvalue reference instead. This lets the new object "steal" the contents of the temporary object instead of copying it. It's particularly useful in the case of something like a string or a vector that has a potentially large amount of dynamically allocated memory that's owned by the object, but can be moved from one object to another just by copying the pointer rather than all the data.